# Single fixed deposit vs multiple fixed deposits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I will be getting 300,000 from one source and 50,000 from another source a year later. Banks here offer 8.75% interest per year regardless of the time you invest with them(Compound interest).

would it make sense if I invest them separately(2 fixed deposits, I invest 300k as soon as I get it and make a FD for 50k when I get it) or should I invest them together(1 fixed deposit, invest 300k wait a year close the FD and make a new FD for 350k) ?

Its kinda like one of those cases, (A + B)^2 vs (A^2 + B^2). There is a difference of 2AB term between the two methods IMO.

I honestly couldn't find relevant tags so I tagged these two topics.

Comment: I did some math and it seems like a single fixed deposit is more profitable, but I rather have someone confirm this for me. This is a huge amount for me.

Comment: Is it simple interest or compound interest?

Comment: Compound interest.

Comment: Well, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: Of course it matters. If you are thinking of holding on to the first sum until you receive the second sum, then investing them together, then you are effectively losing money. You should invest all money as soon as it comes into your possession. Any money you hold could be earning interest instead.

Comment: Are you sure. Cause if you think A = 300,000 and B = 50,000 and I = 0.09.

I am getting 2A*I^2(1 + I) term extra after 4 years.

Comment: @MPW No.. I invest first amount as soon as I get it. Second year when I receive the sum I have two options. Break the first deposit and make a single FD of 350,000 or make the newly received sum as a new FD.

Comment: Ok, I understand. It looks like the answer from JMoravitz sums it up nicely. Fees are the only "gotcha" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the formula $F=P(1+i)^n$ where $F$ is the future value of the deposit, $P$ is the amount deposited, $i$ is the interest per paymentperiod, and $n$ is the number of payment periods.

With $a$ and $b$ being amounts invested separately or together,

$F_{a+b} = (a + b)(1+i)^n = a(1+i)^n + b(1+i)^n = F_{a}+F_{b}$

As such, you should invest the 300k as soon as you get it.  Once receiving the additional 50k you have the option of either creating a new deposit which is separate from the first, or combining the two together.  There will be no difference whatsoever in the amount of interest you receive from the formula.

Where there IS a difference however, is in what additional fees you have to deal with.  Most investment firms will ask for money for creating a new deposit or cancelling a previous deposit.  For information on that, you would need to look at the fine print of whatever contract you sign.

Comment: I agree completely. +1 for you.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot asking this question.

Comment: @user2340452 There is no such thing as a bad question and this information is not knowledge we use regularly.  Without the formula fresh in your mind it would be natural to think that there could be a difference between the two.  I just happened to have taught a unit on mathematical finance last semester to my class, but I still had to stop and think for a moment before posting to confirm what I expected.

Comment: Again, the real life difference between the two are the fees.  Look to see how much you would be charged monthly in terms of flat rates and percentage rates, look at how much it costs to open the deposit, and how much it costs to close the deposit.  I am not familiar with how the banks in your area operate, but hopefully if they are trustworthy they can help work you through the details.  It may also be possible to add the new 50k to the already existing deposit without having to close it first.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks a lot for the answer sir :)